# C#/WPF program suddenly becomes garbage collector bound - how detect?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

I've written a C#/WPF/Windows 10 application for a client that, when started, runs beautifully - it connects to another app over the network, begins data acquisition, as the data comes in it processes it and displays charts and tables to the user.  All is well.

And then Something Bad Happens.

At some point, for no reason I've been able to determine, there's a spike in CPU usage and then the program becomes totally GC-bound.  The client sent me this screenshot:

[image]

The client is running the app in a completely different environment than what I have (he has several hundred thousand dollars of actual data acquisition hardware, I have a simulator) and is several thousand miles away.

When the problem happens, the client is willing to let me take remote control over WebEx and run the debugger, but since the problem is so infrequent I only get called in once the problem has happened - and by then it's too late.  Often times Visual Studio is so overwhelmed by the memory situation that it gives up when asked to do a memory snapshot or even a stack trace (the client has full source so can do full debugging).

Initially I thought this was a memory leak, so for key classes I have code that keeps WeakReferences for each object that is created, and a regular process that scans those lists every 2 minutes, reports back how many objects of each are in existence, and writes that data to a log file.  The log file usually starts getting pretty wonky when the problem starts happening, so the log file data I have doesn't show anything abnormal.

I have also run the ANTS Performance Profiler and Memory Profiler on the application - on my computer.  Neither one show anything unexpected happening.

**QUESTION**

Since this only happens on the client machine, and only happens infrequently, is there something I can put in my code to (1) detect the GC becoming unhappy, and (2) log what it is that is making the GC unhappy?

Comment: You might get better insight if your client manages to get you logging with PerfView: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial

Comment: Is it more or less calling the same routines to get data and display them repeatedly? Can you share any of that code?

Comment: Alas, it's really complex code and it's doing a million different things, I would have to upload the entire code base and I'm not sure the client would appreciate that!